# Change value in url than redirect with .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

we have a Wordpress 4.x website with some plugin that verify the availability of rooms. Now we have an url like this:

http://www.pluto.com/en/check-availability/?lang=en&param1=val1&param2=value2&param3=value3&**param4=838**&param5=value5&param6=value6

We want to change param4=838 with **param4=631** than redirect to the new page:

http://www.pluto.com/en/check-availability/?lang=en&param1=val1&param2=value2&param3=value3&**param4=631**&param5=value5&param6=value6

We want to do this with .htaccess. How can we do that?

Comment: Do you want URL to change in browser as well with `param4=631` ?

Comment: Yes: it is exactly my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?(.*&)?param4=838(&\S*)?\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^en/check-availability/?$ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1param4=631%2 [R=302,NE,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply: it works like a charm. You, sir, are a genious <3

Answer (score 1):

The following permalink rewrite code should be included in your .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

And if you want to be passing arguments in url. Take this example and kindly go through the below link completely

```
 add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array','my_insert_rewrite_rules' );
 add_filter( 'query_vars','my_insert_query_vars' );
 add_action( 'wp_loaded','my_flush_rules' );

 // flush_rules() if our rules are not yet included
  function my_flush_rules(){
     $rules = get_option( 'rewrite_rules' );

   if ( ! isset( $rules['(project)/(\d*)$'] ) ) {
       global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    }
   }

 // Adding a new rule
  function my_insert_rewrite_rules( $rules )
{
     $newrules = array();
      $newrules['(project)/(\d*)$'] = 'index.php pagename=$matches[1]&id=$matches[2]';
    return $newrules + $rules;
 }

 // Adding the id var so that WP recognizes it
  function my_insert_query_vars( $vars )
{
   array_push($vars, 'id');
    return $vars;
   }
```

[link here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Rewrite)